# “Birds come in a flock” “birds come much”

Tags: parallelism

We could say “birds come in a flock” instead of “a flock of birds come.”

Can we say “birds come much” instead of “much birds come”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't

You can't say **much birds**. If there is a large number of birds, you say there are **many birds**.

You can say **many birds come** but it sounds very strange and no native English speaker would phrase it that way (without adding some other information - as I have in the examples below).

If one person was telling another about the approach of a lot of birds, s/he would probably say:

**There are lots of birds coming towards us** or
**There's a flock of birds coming this way**
or, using the simple present tense:
**Many birds come to (visit) the garden each day**
**Many birds come to the islands in spring.**

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "Birds come in a flock" usually means that when birds come a large number of similar birds (a flock) arrive together. This is not true of all birds, as not all birds form large groups, but it may be true of the birds in a particular place. "A flock of birds come" is very awkward as a sentence; it would be better to say "a flock of birds is coming". It can be fine as a fragment, for instance in "When I see a flock of birds come I know the tourists will be taking photographs of them".

Using "much" as you have is incorrect in both examples, and it makes them hard to understand. "Much birds come" sounds as though you mean "many birds are coming". On the other hand "Birds come much" sounds as though you mean "birds come often". In this case it might be the same birds coming back, or it might be different birds.